# Prompt with ng-mouseenter in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to get a button to produce a prompt using ng-mouseeneter, but I can't seem to get it working. Below is the code I have.

```
<span class="button" ng-mouseover="prompt('hello')">Say hello</span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you pass into `ng-mouseover` is not evaluated against the global scope (window object), it's evaluated against an angular $scope.

You can put `window.prompt` on the `$rootScope`:

```
app.run(function($rootScope,$window){

   $rootScope.prompt = $window.prompt;
});
```